# Use mongoose populate to "join" matching subrecords

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using node.js, mongoose (3.5+), mongodb.  Have got two collections in the DB:

```
var AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
});

var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    author: { type: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
});
```

What I would like to do is retrieve an author and populate it with a subcollection (say, "stories") that is looked up from Story and match the author.  Yes, much like a SQL join.

All of the examples out there work on the AuthorSchema having an array of objectids that reference StorySchema objects - that works fine.  But I want to go the opposite direction; partly due to minimizing insert/updates.  If I follow the example, adding a new store requires adding a new Story document and updating the Author.  I want to just insert a new Story that references the Author.

I suspect that populate() is the right way to go, but can't get it to work.  I'm doing something like this:

```
Author.find({name: 'Asimov').populate({
    path: 'stories',
    model: 'Story',
    match: {'author': this['_id']},
}).exec(function(err, authors) {
  console.log(authors);
})
```

But this doesn't return any stories member in the returned authors.  Is this not a populate() solution?  Do I really need to structure the schemas differently?  Or is there some other feature of mongoose/mongo that would do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

In the story schema, do this:

```
author: { type: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Author' }, //or whatever the model name is
```

then you can run

```
Story.find({}).populate('author').exec(function(err,stories) {...});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem.  I want to get a list of all stories that the author wrote by loading and populating the Author.  Your solution requires that I load all stored, populate their authors, then determine if the loaded author is the one I want. I want to query in the reverse direction.